# Issue while passing inputfield value from vf to custom controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, inputfield

I have a VF page through which upon selection it is creating an Agreement record. As per the current implementation record is created successfully but inputfield value is not getting passed to the controller where agreement record creation is happening. I reviewed most of the articles but had no luck. Any help will be appreciated

Can someone please help me with where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add standardController to your apex page.

```
<apex:page extensions="LOAGeneratorController" standardController="Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">


public LOAGeneratorController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) { agreement = new Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c(); }
```

I hope this will resolve your problem.

Comment: No, it gave the below error message

Unknown constructor 'LOAGeneratorController.LOAGeneratorController(ApexPages.StandardController controller)'

Comment: Okay, you also need to add below constructor  -

public LOAGeneratorController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        agreement = new Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c();
    }

Comment: Tried this initially, but I already have a constructor in there if I modified to the structure you mentioned it is throwing this error.

Attempt to de-reference a null object

Comment: can you share the updated changes?

Comment: Updated question with changes you asked to do

Comment: at what line the error is coming? can you comment on all other codes in createAgreement
and just check if you are getting the agreement value or not.

Comment: I commented out getallSAs() method where it is giving this error but no luck

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141836/discussion-between-snehal-and-mukul-mahawariya).